# cloudstorage.listbucket returns no values

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

I am using the cloud storage api with google app engine to generate a listing of folders in a bucket in google cloud storage. I intend to generate this listing on a HTML page.

I am calling this bucket `yyy` for the sake of the example. Here is my code base.

```
from flask import render_template
from flask import Blueprint, redirect, request, abort
from google.appengine.api import users
from thirdpartylib import cloudstorage


admin_routes = Blueprint('admin_routes', __name__)

@admin_routes.before_request
@admin_routes.route('/xxxxx')
def admin_home():
    if not users.is_current_user_admin():
        return redirect(users.create_login_url(request.url))

    files = cloudstorage.listbucket('/yyy', delimiter='/')
    paths = [os_path for os_path in files]

    return render_template('/df/rain.html', paths=paths)
```

The problem i am having is that the files object is empty when I run `dev_appserver.py`.

I know that the cloud storage itself has eventual consistency. But I created the bucket and all its contents were uploaded three days ago. Each of the items has a public URL.

I am unable to figure out why I can't see the `JSON` result.

Comment: on devserver, you don't run on the REAL bucket, but a simulated version for your pc. Your version on your local machine probably doesn't have the bucket. Does this code work on production?

Comment: No it does not. In Production it still returns an empty list (files)

Comment: oh.... THAT'S something else. Dev would've been explainable... prod, a bit less.... lemme check the code you have then ^^